# Node.js programming style with Akka

Tags: functional-programming, closures, akka

I'm wrapping my head around Akka from a node.js perspective. I do the following node.js code below, and it's easy to write & follow.  I can easily extend to handle and aggregate multiple services async, all while holding onto initial argument state data (`a` in example).

```
function handleAction(a, b, callback) {
    remoteServiceOperation(b, function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            // I can reference argument a
            z = a + data; // Do work with a and service result
        }
    });
}
```

Below is rough pseudo for Akka/Scala. My understanding is ask `?` blocks, and should be generally avoided. Attempting to illustrate where my knowledge train ends, and how I'm not clear about how to hold state `a`, aggregate (not-shown), or perhaps structure Akka in a node.js style in general.

```
receive {
    case handleAction(a) =>
        remoteService ! new RemoteServiceOperation(b, c)
        // About to leave and we'll loose `a`
    case remoteServiceOperationResponse(data) =>
        // `a` is afk
}
```

How can I write Akka more like node?

Comment: `?` is not a blocking operation.  I think you may be confused about how the receive function works—it's just Scala pattern matching, writing `case handleAction(a)` wouldn't actually call a function called `handleAction`.

Comment: Thanks, [Akka Futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html#futures-scala) clarifies your points on blocking. Using `?` doesn't seem like the only way out of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your callback well-known style of programming in nodejs maps better of use of `Future`s than Actors.

It looks like this:

```
val service1Res: Future[Int] = service1()
val service2Res: Future[Int] = service2()

for {
  i <- service1Res
  j <- service2Res
} yield i+j + 2
```

Many people say that actors are used best for holding state and futures for things like this. The problem you will encounter when modelling everything with actors is an explosion of messages you will need to define to communicate those actors.

If you really need or want to use actors when you have that `handleAction` message spawn a new actor that will complete the work and will get the `a` in c-tor. Additional benefit of this you will have nice supervision what is probably the least used options of akka and at the same time most valuable.